# Show that the cofinite topological space $(\Bbb N, \tau)$ is second countable.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Show that the cofinite topological space $(\Bbb N, \tau)$ is second countable.

**Fact.** A collection of all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ is countable.

**Proof of Fact.**
Let $\text{Fin}(\Bbb N):=\{A \subseteq \Bbb N : A \ \text{finite} \}$. We want to show that $\text{Fin}(\Bbb N)$ is countable. To this end, define $F_0:=\{\emptyset\}$ and for all $n \in \Bbb N$,
$$F_n:=\{A \subseteq \Bbb N : \max(A)=n\}.$$
Then, $F_n$ is finite for all $n \in \Bbb N \cup \{0\}$. Consequently,
$$\text{Fin}(\Bbb N)=\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N \cup \{0\}} F_n.$$
Since $\text{Fin}(\Bbb N)$ can be expressed as countable union of finite sets, then $\text{Fin}(\Bbb N)$ is countable. Q. E. D.

**Attempt:**
The goal is to show that there exists a countable basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $\tau$.
To this end, notice that
$$\tau=\{\emptyset\} \cup \{A \subseteq \Bbb N: A^c \ \text{is finite}\}.$$
By the claim, we have $|\tau|=|\text{Fin}(\Bbb N)|$. Hence, $\tau$ is countable.
But, $\tau$ is a basis for itself.
Thus, there exists a countable basis $\tau$ for $\tau$. Therefore, we can conclude that $(\Bbb N,\tau)$ is second countable. Q. E. D.

Does this approach correct?
Thanks in advanved.

Comment: Your proof is correct

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks a lot, Sir. But, I still in doubt, how can we conclude from the claim that $|\tau|=|Fin(\Bbb N)|$, since the member of $Fin(\Bbb N)$ is a subset $A$ of $\Bbb N$ in which $A$ is finite, but the member of $\tau$ is a subset $A$ of $\Bbb N$ in which $A^c$ is finite?

Comment: Can we prove the problem by create a bijection $f$ from $Fin(\Bbb N)$ to $\tau$ defined by $f(A)=A^c$, for all $A \in Fin(\Bbb N)$.

Comment: Yes, you got it.